# python mechanize returns wrong 302 location

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to do some automation for this site http://www.beistle.com/ but for visiting the search page i need pid which is generated on the server.
I looked for a response the browser makes and tried to do the same with mechanize in python.

```
import mechanize;
import cookielib;
import   urllib2;
import lxml.html;
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(False)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'),('Referer', 'http://www.beistle.com/'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Host','www.beistle.com'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8') ]
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)
br.open("http://www.beistle.com/");
br.select_form(name='aspnetForm');
br.submit();
```

In browser it returns 302 with correct location in which the pid is written. However mechanize returns "Location: /Search.aspx" which can't be used for searching

Comment: Looks like there is a lot of js logic behind the click event on `submit` button (see `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` function). Are you ok to switch to `selenium`, by the way?